# simple implementation of server and client by using SSE protocol - in JAVA languag

Tags: java, api, rest, jersey, jetty

I am looking for simple implementation of server and client by using SSE (simple sent event) protocol by JAVA language.I know that may possible by jetty or jersy, but looking for simple example to start.

Comment: for guys that think my question is offtopic:  I want to build a REST server that transmit the data woth the clients via SSE protocol ( By java Language). I need to know is that possible os not. besides , my client is not a browser, so by this condition is that possible to use SSE or not. thank you for your help and information.

Comment: I recommend you JeaSSE: https://github.com/mariomac/jeasse it's pretty simple. You can find some examples

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

Add dependency of jersey or add jar

Add dependency of or add jar in your project like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then create a class for server like:

```
@Path("events")
public static class SseResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput getServerSentEvents() {
            final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                            // ... code that waits 1 second
                            final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder
                            = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
                            eventBuilder.name("message-to-client");
                            eventBuilder.data(String.class,
                                "Hello world " + i + "!");
                            final OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build();
                            eventOutput.write(event);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Error when writing the event.", e);
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            eventOutput.close();
                        } catch (IOException ioClose) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(
                                "Error when closing the event output.", ioClose);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            return eventOutput;
        }
}
```

Then on Client use following code:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .register(SseFeature.class).build();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:9998/events");

EventInput eventInput = target.request().get(EventInput.class);
while (!eventInput.isClosed()) {
    final InboundEvent inboundEvent = eventInput.read();
    if (inboundEvent == null) {
        // connection has been closed
        break;
    }
    System.out.println(inboundEvent.getName() + "; "
        + inboundEvent.readData(String.class));
}
```

Check the following link as well as they have detailed information with simple example.

https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/sse.html

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-server-sent-events-java-servlets-example/

http://en.kodcu.com/2013/11/jaxrs-2-html-5-server-sent-events-on-glassfish-4/

Comment: thank you , i visited the links before . it is appreciated to put code that can be run .  anyway , can I use SSE for client-server transmitting or should only use on web-browser ?

Comment: I put my comment on first post , please help me .

Comment: I have added some code taken from jersey link. You can use that for server and client. You can use it in java as well as I shown in client code.

Comment: thank you  , can you please let me know how can i run in in Eclipse , should i define TimeTask for server code ?

Comment: is the @header... missing from the server code ?  i recieve this error

Comment: I have edited my post and added class in it.

Comment: can you please let me know how run the server on eclipse ?

Comment: Run application in which you have implemented jersey. Add this class in it. Now it will be accessible using 'http://localhost:9998/events'. Now run client class whichever your method of calling is. You can put client code in a new java class main method and run that main method using run as java application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104792/discussion-between-liekthewayumove-and-s0haib-nasir).